# Custom Auth logic for local/remote docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, commercial-application

I'm building a new product, and I plan to deliver it to paying subscribers via Docker image only.

My CI is pushing the images to Github's ghcr.io, and - for now - I created a Github PAT (personal access token) with just `package:read` permission in order to distribute to beta testers. So far so good, but:

- Github PATs should be ...personal!
- I already have my homebrew customer portal that produces JWT based "Activation Keys" that expire when the subscription ends. And I would really like to them as `docker login` passwords

### Custom auth Strategies that come to mind

What's the best strategy to let subscribers "docker login" with my custom secret? I came up with few options:

- Create some API endpoints that implements the bare minimum Docker registry API, serving blobs from localhost's docker layers copy?
- Run an instance of docker registry in pull-through mode, but behind a reverse proxy that checks-and-replaces the auth token on the fly?
- Create a reverse-proxy API that replaces `docker login` credentials on the fly, returns a "real" `ghrc.io` registry token (obtained via docker login with master credentials) and responds with a **redirect to `ghcr.io` to any further requests**?
- Use a ready made product/SDK that allows for auth logic replacement?

The #3 would be great, because it would look like I have my own private registry, but I use Github bandwidth for blob downloads (provided docker CLI clients are able to follow redirects!)

Questions for you

- is there any Docker registry server-side library available for any programming language?
- what's the best strategy?

Thanks!